# MySQL error: Non-grouping field is used in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

Is there a way to correct this query so that it works with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled?

```
SELECT LOWER(s) AS lower_s, SUM(i) AS sum_i
FROM t
GROUP BY 1
HAVING LENGTH(lower_s) < 5
```

It gives the error message

> Non-grouping field 'lower_s' is used in HAVING clause

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/749fb9/1)

Comment: In SQL Server you can't use the alias in the having clause. Maybe try `having(LENGTH(LOWER(s)) < 5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why dont you just use `where LENGTH(LOWER(s)) < 5`

It seems the using of `having` is not right here.

According to [having sql wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL))

> A HAVING clause in SQL specifies that an SQL SELECT statement should only return rows where aggregate values meet the specified conditions. It was added to the SQL language because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.[1]

Comment: Accepted because "HAVING is only for aggregate fields" is something I can remember. Hopefully it doesn't affect performance.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use **HAVING** clause in your query. Check below query that will satisfy your requirement.

Try this:

```
SELECT LOWER(s) AS lower_s, SUM(i) AS sum_i
FROM t
WHERE LENGTH(LOWER(s)) < 5
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Length(s) is not always the same as length(lower(s)). (E.g. German `STRAßE` => `strasse`.)

Comment: @jarlh OK, I am not aware of that. Thanks for that, I had updated my answer.

Comment: @jarlh that is actually a weird comment. ß is a lowercase letter so lowercasing ß does not make ss.

Comment: @warly, Well, poor example I understand. (I probably meant the opposite direction... German is not my first language, or second.) But the fact remains, in some languages the length may change when you do upper/lower for certain characters/combinations.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be:

```
SELECT LOWER(s) AS lower_s, SUM(i) AS sum_i 
FROM t 
WHERE LENGTH(lower_s) < 5 
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: What is different from @Saharsh Shah answer

Answer (score 1):

```
select lower_s, SUM(i) AS sum_i
from
(
    SELECT LOWER(s) AS lower_s, i
    FROM t
) dt
where LENGTH(lower_s) < 5
GROUP BY lower_s
```

ANSI SQL compliant answer, having a derived table so you only have to write the `LOWER(s)` expression once.